# How to pass data to child component from parent vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How I can pass the image url to this vue component? I'm moving the code in a separate php file that will hold the `<script>` tag used by Vue, but it will not recognize the passed data from a parent component.

```
Vue.component('theme-parallax',{
  template: '#parallax-tpl',
  data(){
    return{
      pageData: []
    }
  }
});
```

Component markup 
NB: the `page.embedded.parallax_image` will work correctly in the parent component. I'm new to new so To obtain the data I'm using a method in the parent component, It will be great if someone can explain me how to pass data from the main vue instance to all components.

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="parallax-tpl">
    <div class="row m-0">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-parallax p-0" v-prlx.background="{ speed: 0.08 }" :style="{ height: '70vh', backgroundImage: 'url('+page.embedded.parallax_image+')', backgroundSize: 'cover' }"></div>
    </div>
</script>
```

This is how I'm using the component

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="home-tpl">
  <div class="container-fluid p-0">

    <div class="row m-0" v-for="page in pageData">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 p-0" v-if="page.embedded.primary_featured_image">
        <img class="img-fluid w-100" :src="page.embedded.primary_featured_image">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 p-5 mt-5">
        <h1>{{ page.title.rendered }}</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 p-5 mt-5" v-html="page.content.rendered"></div>   
    </div>

    <theme-section data-section="about" data-section-align="left"></theme-section>

    <theme-parallax v-for="page in pageData" ></theme-parallax>

    <theme-section data-section="office" data-section-align="right"></theme-section>

  </div> <!-- end container-fluid -->
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a property in your component and pass the page to it from the parent.

e.g. parent template

```
<theme-parallax v-for="page in pageData" :page="page" :key="page.id"></theme-parallax>
```

If the page doesn't have a unique id, you should use a unique property for the key.

Then in the component

```
Vue.component('theme-parallax',{
  template: '#parallax-tpl',
  props: {
    page: {
      type: Object,
      default: function() {return null;},
    }
  },
  data(){
    return{
      pageData: []
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Ok, I was trying also with the `props` but I'm still learning about vue so your answer will help me a lot. Just a question about the data, I can use this method also to pass the data from the main instance to every component?I wanto to respect DRY principle and have a single function that will fetch the page data in the main instance when needed and pass it to the components, maybe it's the same concept you show in the answer?

Comment: It's a bit of an 'it depends' situation. If you want to reuse the components in other projects, then you should probably pass the data to each component via props. Another way is to use a vuex store, and reference the same vuex data in computed properties inside each of your components, that keeps it dry but adds the vuex store as a dependency, making them harder to reuse.